# Retrieve images from a folder outside web root folder using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to create a small servlet that uploads images and is able to retrieve them in a different page as a slideshow.

I'm able to save them outside the WebApp folder, but while retrieving them I need them to be a part of a JSP which will have other content, apart from the images. Currently, I'm using BufferedImage and ImageIO classes to stream the images one at a time.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\"+file.getName()));
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", response.getOutputStream());
```

The file is checked to be a JPEG file type earlier in the code.

Comment: You shouldn't use ImageIO: you're reading bytes representing a JPG-encoded image, then transforming the stream of bytes into a BufferedImage, then transforming this buffered image into bytes representing a JPG-encoded image. Just read the bytes and send them as is to the response output stream.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that as well by simple reading them using BufferedInputStream and then writing it using BufferedOutputStream. That gives me the same end result. What I want to have is a list of images and not a single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how HTTP and HTML work:

1. The browser asks for an HTML page (first request)
2. The server sends back HTML (and HTML only), containing 3 `<img src="..."/>` tags
3. The browser sends a request to get the bytes of the first image (second request)
4. The server sends back the bytes of the first image
5. The browser sends a request to get the bytes of the second image (third request)
6. The server sends back the bytes of the second image
7. The browser sends a request to get the bytes of the third image (fourth request)
8. The server sends back the bytes of the third image

So, you need a servlet or JSP which generates the HTML page, containing all your `<img src="..."/>` tags. Each of this tag should have the following form:

```
<img src="imageServlet?imageId=564"/>
```

And you need a second servlet, mapped to `imageServlet`, which reads the bytes of the image identified by the `imageId` parameter value from the file system, and write those bytes to the response output stream.

Answer (score 1):

> them I need them to be a part of a JSP which will have other content,

Use image tag in JSP

```
<image src="/context-root/YourServlet?param=value" alt="blah blah"/>
```

Comment: I need to have multiple such image tags. How do I generate them at runtime?