# Displaying uploaded image in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm writing a simple web application that allows users to post advertisements on the website. They can also upload images - I save them outside the webapp directory. And here is my problem - what is the simplest way to display these images inside a JSP Page? The application is deployed on Tomcat.

I will be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: Is that path accessible over the web?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve images from a folder outside web root folder using servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013300/retrieve-images-from-a-folder-outside-web-root-folder-using-servlet)

Comment: The path is accessible - I'm saving the file to tomcat/webapps/images.

Answer (score 1):

If the path where the images are stored isn't accessible via HTTP, I suggest writing a simple servlet.

Here is an excellent [example](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/imageservlet.html#ImageServletServingFromAbsolutePath) from [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)'s blog.