# Unable to load image saved to file system using spring url tag

Tags: java, jsp, url, spring-mvc, image

I'm saving an uploaded image in my controller using this

```
saveImage(context.getRealPath("/resources/image.jpg"), image);
```

And then trying to load the image in a JSP using this

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/image.jpg"/>" />
```

I'm able to access the image using this in the browser address bar

```
home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/SpringMVCTest/resources/image.jpg
```

but the image does not load in the jsp, only a broken link image.

I'm also using `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />` to serve static content.

Why does this not work?

Trivial answer. Everything was correct except I missed a "/" on

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
```

It should be

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The path

> home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/SpringMVCTest/resources/image.jpg

is your server's file system path, Your client won't be able to access it,

Rather put the images in public web area and give relative path for example

```
/contextofyourweb/images/1.jpeg
```

or create a ImageServlet which reads the file from server file system and puts it to servlet response

Related:

- [Retrieve images from a folder outside web root folder using servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013300/retrieve-images-from-a-folder-outside-web-root-folder-using-servlet)

Comment: I only gave the file system path to show the image was being saved. My controller is mapped to "/" hence the use of the resources tag. As the image is being saved to /contextofmyweb/resources/image.jpg why is it not retrievable from there?

Comment: oh ok, so where it is in related to public web area?

Comment: There is no public web area in my app.

Comment: well then write image servlet to read from file system and write image to response, As shown [here](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to resort to Java code in a jsp for something as simple as this. Thankyou for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My requirements are Html5 and Jquery for the views, no JSPs. I have Spring MVC app that simulates a server written in C.

My spring MVC configuration:

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
```

As I am unable to use  tag, I found a jQuery solution that works:

```
    $(function(){
        var ctxRoot = window.location.pathname;
        var imgBtn1Url="/"+ctxRoot.split("/")[1]+"/resources/img/glyphs/glyphicons_173_play.png";
        alert(imgBtn1Url)
        $('#imgBtn1').attr('src', imgBtn1Url);
    });
```

HTML: `<img id="imgBtn1" alt="" data-src="holder.js/300x200" class="thumbnail" />`

In my case ctxRoot=/viper/config because of the url pattern for the spring Dispatcher Servlet. In your case location.pathname may be sufficient.

```
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>conf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/config/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

I hope that other people using Spring MVC will find that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the images on a folder which should be out of the project files because once you re-deploy it, you will surely lose the files in the extracted directory.

Better, save the images at some save place, I am sure, you are saving the path in the database and these images need to be independent of your deployment and the directories in webcontent folder.