# Display image from file in browser using JSP

Tags: jsp

I need to display image in browser using JSP, but I do not know how to do this. photo.image is byte[]. How can I do that? It's my homework, but I have no idea how to do that :-|

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
  <head><title>Nahrát fotku</title></head>
  <body>
  <h2>Fotky</h2>
  <jsp:useBean id="albumDAO" scope="application" type="cz.vse.javaee.album.AlbumDAO"/>
  <table>
      <c:forEach items="${albumDAO.photos}" var="photo">
      <tr>
          <td>${photo.name}</td>
          <td>${photo.description}</td>
          <td><img src="${photo.image}"></td>
      </tr>
      </c:forEach>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013300/retrieve-images-from-a-folder-outside-web-root-folder-using-servlet

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend and you already have all the information you need to find your answers. A few quick searches will land you with multiple examples on how to accomplish your task. Lets just take a few words from your original post to search on:

[jsp display image from byte array](https://www.google.com/search?q=dislay%20image%20jsp&oq=dislay%20image%20jsp&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5833j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=jsp%20display%20image%20from%20byte%20array)

The first page results from Google should provide enough information for you to get started. I would suggest looking at the examples given and incorporating them into a servlet to fetch the image data or use a base64 encoded string from your bean class (example: [How to convert image to byte array and byte array to image in Java](http://mrbool.com/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-image-in-java/25136)). Keep the logic out of your jsp, continue to use expression language (EL) to extract it. (EL is the ${} notation on your jsp.)

EDIT:

As pointed out, this does not directly answer the question, rather I was was trying to point out the answer can easily be obtained through a simple search. I tried to point the OP in a direction that would help them without directly giving the answer.

Part of learning how to develop code is trial and error. If you don't know how to do something, put a little effort into finding the answer before posting. In this example, the answer could be found in the first few results of a Google search.

Regardless, I will post a an answer based on the referenced post, [How to convert image to byte array and byte array to image in Java](http://mrbool.com/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-image-in-java/25136).

As explained by the Mr.Bool blog post, the following code snippet will load an image and convert it into a base64 encoded byte array. This can be used to display the image on the jsp using EL:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try{
      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("icon.png"));
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
      byte[] res=baos.toByteArray();
      String encodedImage = Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
              System.out.println(“The encoded image byte array is shown below.Please use this in your webpage image tag.\n”+encodedImage);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(“Some problem has occurred. Please try again”);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

To then display the image on the screen, you would include something similar to the follow example proposed by Mr.Bool:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>csanuragjain</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <img  src="data:image/png;base64,PASTE THE BYTE ARRAY HERE WHICH IS OBTAINED FROM JAVA PROGRAM" alt="IMG DESC">
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now. To make this work in your bean class, you would create a method perform the same logic listed in the main method and return a string (from the encodedImage output) and reference it with EL.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.